# Data at root level is invalid. working with ajax wcf service, and cant figure it out

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, wcf

I am not sure what this means to me.  I been picking at it over the last day or 2.  I have other functions which work with "GET" but this is the first "POST" hit in the process chain.  Does anyone have an idea whats wrong?

Error Output:

```
{"ExceptionDetail":{
      "HelpLink":null,
      "InnerException":{
            "HelpLink":null,
            "InnerException":null,
            "Message":"The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.",
            "StackTrace":"   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)\u000d\u000a   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()\u000d\u000a   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()\u000d\u000a   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)",
             "Type":"System.Xml.XmlException"},
         "Message":"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SaveXml'. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.",
         "StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)","Type":"System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException"},
    "ExceptionType":"System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException",
    "Message":"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SaveXml'. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.","StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"}
```

CALL:

```
//when stringified, it looks correct.  No real obvious holes.
//the variables in data are strings, and are recognized correctly in the request payload of the file.

var settings = {
    url: "webservices/FormServices.svc/SaveXml",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/xml",
    data: JSON.stringify({ auth: auth, server: server, datasource: datasource, FileId:FileId, XML:xml }),
    success: success,
    error: error
};
console.log("Settings", settings);
return $.ajax(settings);
```

IService:

```
//this is of a class i made with a [ServiceContract]

[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SaveXml(string auth, string server, string datasource, string FileId, string XML);
```

Service:

```
public string SaveXml(string auth, string server, string datasource, string FileId, string XML)
    {
    string response = "-1";
    return response;
    }
```

Binding:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="test.webservices.FormServices" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="test.webservices.FormServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="test.webservices.IFormServices"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings />
<client />
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="test.webservices.FromRequestAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="test.webservices.FormServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debug">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are trying it with json as the data and specifying a contentType of "text/xml" instead of dataType of json.

You should try this:

```
var settings = {
    url: "webservices/FormServices.svc/SaveXml",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ auth: auth, server: server, datasource: datasource, FileId:FileId, XML:xml }),
    success: success,
    error: error
};
```

Comment: Now i get it.  I was saying text/xml, but it needs to be json cause im sending up a selection.  Let me just confirm it before i ogive you the answer points

Comment: I now get this error:
**"The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.**  I attempted this for when data was an object AND stringified.

Comment: I am not sure why it is labelled as: *Raw*.

Comment: on my ajax calls, I have contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8".  Give that a shot.

Comment: I have it working.  I will make just a minor edit to your post so that way its correct